# Application architecture that is COMPLETELY view layer agnostic

Tags: c++, qt, architecture, backbone.js, web-frameworks

I want to write a C++ application framework which will be **completely** view agnostic. Ideally, I want to be able to use either of the following as the "frontend"

1. Qt
2. Web front end

I am aware of developments like web toolkit (wt) etc, but I want to avoid these because of at least one of the following reasons:

1. They use cgi/fastcgi approach (when using Apache)
2. AFAIK, they impose a "frontend" framework on you - for example, I cannot use CakePHP, Symfony, Django etc to create the web page and only have "widgets" in the page binding to the server side C++ application. I would like to be free to use whichever web framework I want, so I can benefit from the many popular and established templating frameworks out there (e.g. Smarty etc).

I think some variation of the MVC  pattern (not sure which variation) could work well in this instance.

This is how I intend to proceed:

- The model and controller layer are implemented in C++
- A plugin sits between the controller and the view
- The view is implemented using either QT or a third party web framework
- Communication between the view (frontend) and the plugin is done using either:

  i.  events for a QT frontend

  ii. AJAX/PUSH mechanism for a web frontend (maybe backbone.js can be used here?)

Is there a name for the pattern I describe above - and (before I start coding), what (if any) are there any gotchas/performance issues (other than network latency) that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sounds of it, it is an MVC, with the plugin implementing a [Bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern) between the controller and view.  I could not locate a variant of MVC that specifically has a bridge as a participant in the design; however, none of them preclude a bridge, or other patterns, from collaborating or implementing the MVC.

The difficulty in implementing this will likely come from the bridge abstraction.  It can be difficult to:

- Prevent implementation details from affecting the abstraction.  For example, if implementation `A` has an error code that is only meaningful to implementation `A` and implementation `B` has an error code that is similar but occurs under different conditions, then how will the errors pass through the abstraction without losing too much meaning?
- Account for behavioral differences between implementations.  This generally requires a solid understanding of the implementation being abstracted so that pre-conditions and post-conditions can be met for the abstraction.  For example, if implementation `A` supports asynchronous reads, and implementation `B` only supports synchronous reads, then some work will need to be done in the abstraction layer to to account for the threading.
- Find an acceptable compromise between decoupling and performance.  It will be a balancing act.  As always, try to avoid premature optimizations.  Often times, it easier to introduce a little coupling for the sake of performance, than it is to decouple highly performant code.

Also, consider leveraging other patterns to help in the decoupling.  For example, if concrete type `Foo` needs to be passed through the abstraction layer, and implementation `A` will convert it to `Foo_A`, while implementation will convert it to `Foo_B`, then consider having the plugin provide an [Abstract Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern).  `Foo` would become an abstract base class for `Foo_A` and `Foo_B`, and the plugin would provide a factory to create objects that implement `Foo`, allowing the controller to allocate the exact type the plugin is expecting.

Comment: I agree, sounds very MVC. You could call the plugin a "DAO" or "CRUD" object. In that case, it would act as the "V" to your model and controller on the backend with which another MVC on the front-end could use as a conduit.